# Should Google Maps and Apple Maps businesses be registered with the owner's account?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, google-maps

It is OK to register businesses at Google Maps or Apple Maps platforms with the owner account? I want to manage some customers' businesses with the reviews, ads, analytics and Disqus data, but I'm not sure whether to register them with each individual owner account or register them all with my account.

For example, customers A and B each have a business. So the first option is to register the customer A business at Google and Apple with the customera@gmail.com account and the same for customer B with customerb@gmail.com. The second option is to register both businesses with myaccount@gmail.com.

Which is more advisable or suitable to do? I already monitor the traffic with Google Analytics with my own account. Should I change that in order to let the owners monitor their businesses?

Answer (score 1):

It is okay to register a Google My Business account with the business owner's google account, or a google account you create for them on their behalf.

This is the better solution for the business owner as well, because it gives them full control and access, and it avoids the business owner having to log in to your own account if they want to make changes.

I recommend that you take one extra step and add your personal Google account (the one you use to track Analytics) as a Manager of the client's Google My Business account. That way, you'll be able to log in to your own account to manage their page later on. 
See https://support.google.com/business/answer/4573962?hl=en

I don't have any experience with Apple Maps accounts, so I can't answer that part.